# alignment for different ios device

Tags: ios, iphone, alignment

I am new to iOS programming. I made an application for iPhone retina 4-inch. Now I want to customise my code in order for it to run on an iPhone retina-3.5 inch and iPhone 5.

I tried to create an if query for `self.view.frame.size.width` and `self.view.frame.size.height`, but I get a "Not assignable" error.

Can anyone tell me how to specify conditions for setting up the workspace nicely in all devices? If possible please give me the exact screen-size of all that devices.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size; 
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;
```

References: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html

Answer (score 2):

```
You look at the device's screen size (in points) and from that surmise if it's an iPad or iPhone etc., and then use hard-coded values for the screen sizes.

Here's some code to get the screen size:

CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

Be aware that width and height might be swapped, depending on device orientation.
```

Answer (score 0):

to compare screen size include this macro and use it any where necessary

```
    #define isPhone5 ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
```

if you want to compare screen sizes only then reduce the above macro to

```
    #define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE
```

For example in your `.m` file

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    #define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE //hear u put the macro and use it anywhere in this file

 @interface ViewController ()<FootballPlayerDelegate>//confirms to this delegate

 @end

 @implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     if(isiPhone5)
     {
        NSLog(@"I am 4inch screen");

     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"I am 3.5inch screen");
     }
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }
```

Comment: sorry but i am new in ios and dont knew wher to put & how to use your macro. I have create Buttons in viewdidload, So I just want to change size of my Buttons according to different ios device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this In your .M file:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:1.0];

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)

    {
        [self setFrameForLeftAndRightOrientation];
    }

    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait )

    {
        [self setFrameForPortraitAndUpsideDownOrientation];
    }
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)

    {
        [self setFrameForLeftAndRightOrientation];
    }

    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)

    {
        [self setFrameForPortraitAndUpsideDownOrientation];
    }


}
-(void)setFrameForLeftAndRightOrientation
{

    if(IS_IPAD)

    {
        //Write here code for iPad (Landscape mode)
    }

  else if(IS_IPHONE)
    {

        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
        {
            //Write code here for iPhone 5    (Landscape mode) 
        }
        else
        {
           //Write code here for iPhone(3.5 inch) (Landscape mode) 
        }
    }
}

-(void)setFrameForPortraitAndUpsideDownOrientation
{
    if(IS_IPAD)
    {

    }
    else if(IS_IPHONE)
    {

        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @yourwish, if this solved your problem. Put a tick on this answer. Because it solved mine too ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
  #define IS_IPHONE_SIMULATOR ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]model] isEqualToString : @"iPhone     Simulator"])
  #define IS_IPHONE ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]model] isEqualToString : @"iPhone"])
  #define IS_IPOD_TOUCH ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]model] isEqualToString : @"iPod Touch"])
  #define IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 [[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds].size.height >= 568.0f
  #define ITS_IPHONE5 ( IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 )



 if (ITS_IPHONE5)

 {

 }

 else

{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code in  project-Prefix.pch file in supporting file folder.

```
    #define IS_IPHONE_SIMULATOR ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]model] 
            isEqualToString : @"iPhone     Simulator"])
    #define IS_IPHONE ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]model] isEqualToString : @"iPhone"])
    #define IS_IPOD_TOUCH ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]model] isEqualToString : @"iPod     Touch"])
    #define IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 [[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds].size.height >= 568.0f
    #define ITS_IPHONE5 ( IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 )
```

Copy and Past This Code After That in your .m File past the first code i give you...
  Dont need to write size on viewdidload write only in these cots

```
       if  (IS_IPAD)
            {

            }
          else if(IS_IPHONE)
             {

              if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
                {

                }
         else
                {

                }
             }
```